# display knockout viewmodel child elements elsewhere

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

I have the following viewmodel defined:

```
function BookCartViewModel() {
this.Books = ko.observableArray([]);
this.Categories = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var Book = function (data) {
   this.ISBN = ko.observable(data.ISBN);
   this.BookID = ko.observable(data.BookID);
   this.BookName = ko.observable(data.Name);
   this.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
   this.Publisher = ko.observable(data.Publisher);
   this.PublishedDate = ko.observable(data.PublishedDate);
   this.Authors = ko.observableArray(data.Authors);
   this.Category = ko.observable(data.Category);
   this.Reviews = ko.observableArray([]);
   var items = $.map(data.BookReviews, function (d) { return new Review(d) });

   this.ShowReviews = function () {
   }
 }

var Review = function (data) {
   this.ReviewID = ko.observable(data.ReviewID);
   this.Reviewer = ko.observable(data.ReviewerName);
   this.Email = ko.observable(data.Email);
   this.BookID = ko.observable(data.FkBookID);
   this.ReviewDate = ko.observable(data.ReviewDate);
   this.Comments = ko.observable(data.Comments);
   this.Rating = ko.observable(data.Rating);
}
```

My view is as follows which displays the books in a table structure:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach:Books">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%; text-align:left;" data-bind="text:ISBN"></td>
        <td style="width:20%; text-align:left;" data-bind="text:BookName"></td>
        <td style="width:30%; text-align:left;" data-bind="text:Authors"></td>
        <td style="width:10%; text-align:left;" data-bind="text:Price"></td>
        <td style="width:10%; text-align:left;" data-bind="text:PublishedDate"></td>
        <td style="width:10%; text-align:left;">
            <input id="btnShowReviews" type="button" value="Reviews"  data-      bind="click:ShowReviews" />
        </td>
    </tr>       
   </tbody>
```

Now what I want to do is to show the reviews for a book in a SEPERATE table, underneath when you click on reviews button. How can I accomplish this with the way I have defined my viewmodel? Or does it need to be changed?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function BookCartViewModel() {
    this.Books = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.Categories = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.SelectedBook = ko.observable();

    this.selectBook = function(book, event) {
        this.SelectedBook(book);
    }
}
```

and

```
<div id="bookReview" data-bind="if: SelectedBook">
  <table data-bind="foreach: SelectedBook.Reviews">
    <!-- ... -->
  </table>
</div>
```

Now all you need is a button that writes to `SelectedBook` via `data-bind="click: $root.selectBook"`.

Comment: I have another question though, what If I wanted to add a book outside the above table? I'm aware how to do it within the foreach binding of the table, but I do it in a separate div outside it, how do I do the data binding? and how should the model change?

Comment: You can use `ko.utils.arrayFirst()` to find a book by it's ID or ISBN or any other property within the `Books` array and call `this.selectBook(book)` with the returned book. See http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html for a description on useful utility functions. Of course you could use a plain old `for` loop or jQuery's `$.each()` to do the same. Any `Book` instance you store in `SelectedBook` will work, how you obtain it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make one variable of type Book which will be stored the selected or book for review
2. Make one div which will be visible if book for review is not null, then map the needed properties
3. If there is no selection for book for review then hide that div